# Properties.Settings Not Available in VS 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studio 2010, I am trying to use the `Properties.Settings` functionality but am unable to see any evidence of it. Is it in this version? Let me know please. Thanks!

Comment: What you expect to see? Can you provide some code?

Comment: As @SLaks said , win or web project?

Comment: just click on Properties

Answer (score 1):

`Properties.Settings` is a class (specifically a `Settings` class in the `Properties` namespace) generated by Visual Studio and is not part of the framework.  You can create that class by going to the "Settings" tab in the project properties.  If a settings file does not exist, it will ask if you want to create one.

I believe end-user apps (Winforms, Console Apps, web sites, etc.) create one by default, but class libraries do not.

Comment: So I have to do a `using Properties;`?

Comment: You don't _have_ to - it would just let you use `Settings` instead of `Properties.Settings`